# How to render a List with Groovy's MarkupBuilder

Tags: xml, groovy, dictionary

I am converting a Map to XML using the Groovy [MarkupBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+XML+using+Groovy%27s+MarkupBuilder).  This Map can contain simple key/value pairs, other Maps, or Lists of Maps.  I am piggybacking from the code [here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/431003).

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def map = [
    key1:'value1',
    key2:'value2',
    nestedMap : [
        key1:'bar1',
        key2:'bar2'
    ],
    select : [
        [option:'foo1'],
        [option:'foo2']
    ]
]

Closure renderMap( Map map ){
    return { 
        for ( entry in map ){
            switch( entry.value.getClass() ){
                case Map :
                    "${entry.key}" renderMap( entry.value )
                break
                case List:
                    entry.value.collect { listEntry ->
                        "${entry.key}" renderMap( listEntry )
                    }
                    break
                default :
                     "${entry.key}"( "${entry.value}" )
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
new MarkupBuilder(writer).root renderMap(map)

println writer.toString()
```

This part I'm concerned about prints out:

```
  <select>
    <option>foo1</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>foo2</option>
  </select>
```

However, I am wondering if there is a way to get the select to encapsulate both of the options, like so:

```
<select>
    <option>foo1</option>
     <option>foo2</option>
  </select>
```

I've tried playing around with the placement of the key, but to no avail.  Am I going about this all wrong, or should I not be using the builder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will do what you want. The first two overloads take a map or a collection, and return a composed closure that can be passed to the builder method of the enclosing element to add the contents of the map or collection to the builder.

The third is a fallback, and just returns its arguments so they can be passed to the builder method. This handles the strings, but you could also pass it a closure if you want. I replaced the second `option` element in the map you provided as an example of that.

[`ComposedClosure`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ComposedClosure.html) was added in Groovy 1.8, so this won't work in earlier versions.

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

Closure buildxml(final Map map)
{
    final compose = { f, tag, content -> f >> { "$tag"(buildxml(content)) } }
    return map.inject(Closure.IDENTITY, compose)
}

Closure buildxml(final Collection col)
{
    final compose = { f, content -> f >> buildxml(content) }
    return col.inject(Closure.IDENTITY, compose)
}

def buildxml(final content)
{
    return content
}

def map = [
    key1:'value1',
    key2:'value2',
    nestedMap : [
        key1:'bar1',
        key2:'bar2'
    ],
    select : [
        [option:'foo1'],
        { option('foo2') },
    ],
]

final writer  = new StringWriter()
final builder = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

builder.root buildxml(map)

assert writer as String == '''\
<root>
  <key1>value1</key1>
  <key2>value2</key2>
  <nestedMap>
    <key1>bar1</key1>
    <key2>bar2</key2>
  </nestedMap>
  <select>
    <option>foo1</option>
    <option>foo2</option>
  </select>
</root>'''.stripIndent()
```

Comment: Was able to dramatically simplify this now that it's not 3AM. The overloads for Map and Collection still bug me a little though. They seem redundant, but offhand I can't think of a way to combine them that's cleaner than just having two nearly identical methods.

Answer (score 1):

does

```
case List:
    "${entry.key}" entry.value.collect {
        renderMap it
    }
    break
```

get you anywhere? not at a computer to check atm though,  but it feels right?

Comment: I had actually tried that, with no luck.  It prints out: `<select>[Script1$_renderMap_closure1@1075c5, Script1$_renderMap_closure1@a3e8f5]</select>`.  Thanks though.

Comment: ahhh, yeah. you could call the closures with `renderMap( it )()`, but that would probably break deeper nested structures. I'll have a think