# Dynamic Map and XML Generation in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, dictionary, soapui

I am trying to generate the following XML dynamically. It is a list of elements (which can also have sub-lists and sub-sublists, and so on).

```
<root>
  <Fault>
    <Code>100</Code>
    <Type>USER</Type>
    <DetailList>
      <DetailText>Incorrect name</DetailText>
      <DetailText>Incorrect ID</DetailText>
    </DetailList>
    <severity>ABORT</severity>
  </Fault>
  <Fault>
    <Code>200</Code>
    <Type>SYSTEM</Type>
    <DetailList>
      <DetailText>Invalid DB</DetailText>
      <DetailText>Invalid Access</DetailText>
    </DetailList>
    <severity>CRITICAL</severity>
  </Fault>
</root>
```

I'll have access to the data source only one line item at a time, so figured I'll need to store the data in some kind of a map. I started creating a dynamic map to hold a list of items that can be written out as XML as provided in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13098148/1917284).

This is the structure I am expecting to achieve -

```
def map = [
     ["Fault": [
        "Code":"100",
        "Type":"USER",
        "DetailList" : [
            ["DetailText":"Incorrect name"],
            ["DetailText":"Incorrect ID"]
            ],
        "severity":"ABORT"
        ]],
    ["Fault": [
        "Code":"200",
        "Type":"SYSTEM",
        "DetailList" : [
            ["DetailText":"Invalid DB"],
            ["DetailText":"Invalid Access"]
            ],
        "severity":"CRITICAL"
        ]]
]
```

At run time, I will be getting these values dynamically, so for now this is the portion that I have been trying to get to work as above -

```
 String root = "Fault"
 String item1 = "Code"
 String item2 = "Type"
 String nextLevel = "DetailList"
 String levelItem = "DetailText"
 String innerItem1 = "Incorrect name"
 String innerItem2 = "Incorrect ID"

 def dummyMap = { [:].withDefault{ owner.call() } }()
 def map = { [:].withDefault{ owner.call() } }()
 map.put(root, [:])
 map."$root"[item1] = "100"
 map."$root"[item2] = "USER"
 map."$root"["$nextLevel"] = [:]
 x = map."$root"["$nextLevel"]
 x."$levelItem" = innerItem1
```

This is where I'm stuck. I cannot figure out how to add the second item in the list at the same level, without overwriting the first one.

I am absolutely new to Groovy, so I may not be doing it in the best possible way. If there's any other way I could achieve the resultant XML, I would be glad to work on your suggestion.

Comment: why not use `[XMLSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html)` which would give you a property like access to the xml (same like one could do with a map)?

Comment: also, what do you mean by ``I'll have access to the data source only one line item at a time''.  Is it huge or do you really only get one line per e.g. methodcall and can not accumulate?  or is it just split by linebreak and a list anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is around here:

```
 map."$root"["$nextLevel"] = [:]
 x = map."$root"["$nextLevel"]
 x."$levelItem" = innerItem1
```

You are creating a Map (`[:]`) for `DetailList`, but as the name suggests, you need a list here.  So you would have to use `[]` and then add your items there. E.g.

```
 map."$root"["$nextLevel"] = [] // list!  no map
 map."$root"."$nextLevel" << ["$itemLevel": item1] // add new maps at end of list
 map."$root"."$nextLevel" << ["$itemLevel": item2] // ...
```

If your ultimate goal is to create a map to have "property"-like access to the code there (e.g `root[0].Fault.Code`) then you can as well use [XMLSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html), which would give you without such hastle something similar (`root.Fault[0].Code.text()`).

Comment: This worked for me. It was failing initially though since I was using `$levelItem` as the var name, while your sample had `$itemLevel`, but once I figured that out, it worked out great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add multiple items to a map, you could make your map a map of arrays instead of just a regular map. Then, to add a second item under the same key, you would just tack it on the to end of an array.

However, I'd be wary of implementing this by hand, especially using a map - which might cause you problems when you try to pull the data out and the items comes out in a random order, rather than the order in which you added them. Better to find yourself an XML library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building anything in Groovy (such as XML) you always was to use a `Builder`.

```
def builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder()

// using your variables from above!

def xmlRoot = builder.root {
    "$root" {
        "$item1"(100)
        "$item2"("USER")
        "$nextLevel" {
            "$levelItem"(innerItem1)
            "$levelItem"(innerItem2)
        }
        severity("ABORT")
    }
    // repeat as necessary
}
```

Generates:

```
<root>
  <Fault>
    <Code>100</Code>
    <Type>USER</Type>
    <DetailList>
      <DetailText>Incorrect name</DetailText>
      <DetailText>Incorrect ID</DetailText>
    </DetailList>
    <severity>ABORT</severity>
  </Fault>
</root>
```